# output XML nodes out into individual files

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am trying to create individual files from the nodes of a XML file. My issue is no matter what way I try it I seem to be getting stuck in a nested loop and I either keep rewriting each file until they are just the same node data over and over, or I run all of the nodes per loop instance. I'm sure this should be pretty easy but I'm getting hung up somewhere.

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("original_copy_mod.xml"))

 doc.xpath("//nodes/node").each do |item| 

      item.xpath("//div[@class='meeting-date']/span/@content").each do |date| 

      date = date.to_s
      split_date = date.split('T00')
      split_date = split_date[0].gsub("-","_")
      split_date = split_date + ".pcf"


       File.open(split_date,'w'){ |f| f.write(item)}
      end 
        
 end
```

This is another attempt that I don't understand why is failing to create all the pages. This only creates one page, but if I use a "puts" the count does iterate through all 101 nodes.

```
 doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("original_copy_mod.xml"))

 doc.xpath("//nodes/node").each do |item| 


      date = item.xpath("//no-name/div[@class='meeting-date']/span/@content").to_s
      split_date = date.split('T00')
      split_date = split_date[0].gsub("-","_")
      split_date = split_date + ".pcf"
      File.open(split_date,'w'){ |f| f.write(item)}
     
        
     end
```

For further clarification, this is an example of the nodes that I'm trying to create into pages.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<nodes>

<node>
    <no-name><div class="meeting-title">Meeting-a</div>
        <div class="meeting-date"><span class="date-display-single" property="dc:date" datatype="xsd:dateTime" content="a-2021-11-29T00:00:00-06:00">Monday, November 29, 2021</span></div>
    </no-name>
    <no-name><div class="past-mtg-icons">
        <div>
            <span><a href="/final.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="agenda-icon.svg"/></a></span>
            <span><a href="final.pdf" target="_blank">Agenda</a></span>
        </div>


        <div>
            <span><a href="https://9949973" target="_blank"><img src="webcast-icon.svg"/></a></span>
            <span><a href="https://9949973" target="_blank">11/29</a></span>
        </div>

        </div>
        <div class="meeting-body"></div></no-name>
</node>

<node>
    <no-name><div class="meeting-title">Meeting-b</div>
        <div class="meeting-date"><span class="date-display-single" property="dc:date" datatype="xsd:dateTime" content="e-2021-09-10T00:00:00-05:00">Friday, September 10, 2021</span></div>
    </no-name>
    <no-name><div class="past-mtg-icons">
        <div>
            <span><a href="/final.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="agenda-icon.svg"/></a></span>
            <span><a href="final.pdf" target="_blank">Agenda</a></span>
        </div>


        <div>
            <span><a href="https://9949973" target="_blank"><img src="webcast-icon.svg"/></a></span>
            <span><a href="https://9949973" target="_blank">11/29</a></span>
        </div>

        </div>
        <div class="meeting-body"></div></no-name>
</node>

<node>
    <no-name><div class="meeting-title">Meeting-c</div>
        <div class="meeting-date"><span class="date-display-single" property="dc:date" datatype="xsd:dateTime" content="f-2021-08-13T00:00:00-05:00">Friday, August 13, 2021</span></div>
    </no-name>
    <no-name><div class="past-mtg-icons">
        <div>
            <span><a href="/final.pdf" target="_blank"><img src="agenda-icon.svg"/></a></span>
            <span><a href="final.pdf" target="_blank">Agenda</a></span>
        </div>


        <div>
            <span><a href="https://9949973" target="_blank"><img src="webcast-icon.svg"/></a></span>
            <span><a href="https://9949973" target="_blank">11/29</a></span>
        </div>

        </div>
        <div class="meeting-body"></div></no-name>
</node>

</nodes>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
date = item.xpath("//no-name/div[@class='meeting-date']/span/@content").to_s
```

By using // you are breaking out of the scope of the node you are iterating in. Removing the slashes you preserve the scope of the node.

```
date = item.xpath("no-name/div[@class='meeting-date']/span/@content").to_s
```

Comment: This worked. 
Oh man such a simple error to fix, facepalm. Thank you so much Alex!

Answer (score 0):

When you use `w` option it always rewrite onto the file. What you need is to create or append to the file, it's done with the `a` option. So you can try this:

`File.open(split_date,'a'){ |f| f << item }`

PS. Be sure that split_date as the name of the file is uniq for each node since you want a separate file per node

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work, it ended up writing the entire XML document to each of the individual files. `w` seemed to be closer as it initially would create the file with the desired data however with each loop iteration the file would be overwritten again and again causing all files to be the same XML node in the end.

Comment: @user3610760 Well, it's pretty confusing. Can you share any sample of `original_copy_mod.xml` ?

Comment: I cannot because I would have to strip out all the node data for security purposes. but I can add some more nodes for context. Thank you for looking into this for me.

Comment: At least we'll need the structure of the XML file. Otherwise, it'll be tricky to get an accurate solution

Comment: That is as complicated as the xml gets, just about 100 of these nodes that I need to create individual files for. Thankyou.